# Opening the link inside div#id while using anchor tag with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have IDtab when you click option1 w/c have a `href=#option1` it will show the content in `<div id=option1></div>`

Now I'm trying to figure it out how can I use javascript or jquery. When I click option5 it will open the link inside the `<div id=container2></div>`

For example

This is the code im using

```
<a class='ext-link' href=#option5/>External Link</a>
<div id='content5' ><a href='http://google.com' >link</a></div>
```

I'm trying to figure it how that whenever I click the `<a class='ext-link' href='#option5' >External Link</a>`

The link inside the `<div id='content5'/><a href=google.com/>link</a></div>` is gonna open

I'm using wordpress theme and I wanna modify it but im still lacking in coding skill on jquery and javascript.

In short sentence, when you click the `class='ext-link'` the link inside the div is gonna open.

Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: That will be blocked by most browser defaults

Comment: You are trying to change the `href` of an anchor using javascript right? If that is the case, my above comment is very true.

Comment: what im trying to do is when you click the href=#option5 a link will be opened in the the default it will show the code in the content5

Comment: To expand on what @Adam mentioned: You can only access content from external domains via AJAX, if that external domain actively supports this – it is called CORS, go look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.ext-link').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location=$(id + ' a').attr('href');
  });
});
<script>
```

And make sure that href="#content5" instead of #option5. If you can't then some search and replace can help you there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. they actually the same I just needed to change it so its much better to read it. And the code doesn't seem to work, I might be wrong but the code doesn't tell that the link is gonna open in the #content5.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that I needed to replace the id + ' a'. The code is working, thank you